# Is there any equivalent command grep -nP "\t" some_file , using sed or awk

Tags: linux, file, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to find the occurance of tab in a file **some_file** and print those line with leading line number.
**grep -nP "\t" some_file** works well for me but I want sed or awk equivalent command for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To emulate: `grep -nP "\t" file.txt`

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/\t/ { print NR ":" $0 }' file.txt
```

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
< file.txt sed -n '/\t/{ =;p }' | sed '{ N;s/\n/:/ }'
```

Comment: Thanx this is what I wanted. Can you tell from where I can know more about such file processing using awk and GNU sed and regular expressions more effectively.

Comment: @Akinza: That's a tough question. If you see the `awk` [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), you may like to read up on 'patterns and actions' and 'string functions'. As for `sed`, I like [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) tutorial. Otherwise, I hear [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) is a great site to learn from :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always do it in sed:

```
cat -n test.txt | sed -n "/\t/p"
```

Unfortunately, sed can only print line numbers to stdout with a new line, so in any case, more than one command is necessary. A more lengthy (unnecessary so) version of the above, but one only using sed, would be:

```
sed = test.txt | sed -n "N;s/\n/ /;/\t/p"
```

but I like the one with `cat` more. CATS ARE NICE.

Comment: Thanx but it does not prints line number in the output. I tried it in Ubuntu terminal like this-
sed -n "/\t/p" tab.txt

Comment: yes, right, my bad. You can use cat -n to precede the lines with numbers.